# Linear gradient not applying in Webkit with d3 generated SVG

Tags: svg, webkit, d3.js, linear-gradients

I'm creating a specific implementation for a d3.js graph, and it seems that when creating an SVG document dynamically, `linearGradient`s are not working on Webkit browsers (tested only on Chrome, of the Webkit family), while Gecko is showing the expected behavior.

How do I conclude it has to do with dynamic generation, or d3? I tried copying the resulted document into an empty page, and the gradient came to life.

The d3 code initializes the document first:

```js
// in construction:
// ...
svg = d3.select(el)
    .append('svg:svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height),
defs = svg.append('svg:defs'),
linearGradient1 = defs.append('svg:linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'linear-gradient-1')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 1)
    .attr('x2', 6.123233995736766e-17)
    .attr('y2', 0),
linearGradient1Stop1 = linearGradient1.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '0%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#e3e5e8'),
    // several other stops here ...
```

… than refreshes the renderer, e.g. after adding "nodes" to the graph data struct, on demand (*note: `selfRef.node` is simply a handle to the d3 selector of all the nodes*):

```js
// called e.g. when adding new nodes:
refresh: function() {
    // ...
    // add new nodes
    var g = selfRef.node.enter().append('svg:g').attr('class', 'node');

    g.append('svg:rect')
        .attr('width', 144)
        .attr('height', 42)
        .attr('rx', 3)
        .attr('ry', 3)
        .attr('fill', 'url(#linear-gradient-1)')
        .style('stroke', '#4d4d4d')
        .style('stroke-width', 1)

    // ...
}
```

Here's the generated document, it's nothing special:

```svg
<svg width="1889" height="400">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-1" x1="0" y1="1" x2="6.123233995736766e-17" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e3e5e8"></stop>
            <stop offset="11%" stop-color="#e6e8ec"></stop>
            <stop offset="59%" stop-color="#eff2fa"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0.6" stop-color="#f2f6ff"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <g class="node" 
           transform="translate(1113.425033222223,312.1412317958371)">
            <rect width="144" height="42" rx="3" ry="3" 
                  fill="url(#linear-gradient-1)" 
                  style="stroke: #4d4d4d; stroke-width: 1px;"></rect>
            <!-- some other shapes of the node... -->
        </g>
        <!-- etc. etc., some more node groups here... -->
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### Things I have tried

- Pulling the element referencing the gradient outside any group.
- Adding `version` declaration to the SVG with varying values (maybe it only appears on 1.1?)
- Wrapping the reference in quotes (i.e. `fill="url('#linear-gradient-1')"`) or omitting the dashes from the id, thinking Webkit is less lenient here.

#### Note

[Robert Longson mentioned that case matters in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888114/547020), and, weird enough, it seems that when pasting the document in an empty page (in the Chrome's dev-tools), the linear gradient element transforms to camel-case format (though it doesn't show in the DOM view, all is lowercase there). I discovered this after [diffing](http://www.mergely.com/TbgwrM3n/) the results of my d3 generated code and the pasted static document. What's up with that?

---

#### TL;DR

How come generating dynamic SVG gradients don't work when running in Chrome, and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `svg:` namespace when adding elements?

Comment: the namespace is used only when constructing new elements (appending them). are you suggesting to remove it altogether when constructing `linearGradient`s?

Comment: anyways i've tried it, to no avail. thanks

Comment: Does [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1086421) work for you?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff - on Webkit? yes. that's what puzzles me.

Comment: Copy the source locally and see if it works: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1086421/f1eeec12978b8341f087be773549ef5296222bca/ If it does modify it a bit at a time till it looks like what you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson, that demo is not working locally, seems like you were spot on with that bug...

Comment: You could try renaming the file to end .xhtml perhaps

Comment: I thought I'd add, for posterity's sake, that I'm still having an issue with dynamically rendering gradient fills in Chrome. I've got a list of items that can be filtered using the VueJS library. Each of these items has a d3 graph. Occasionally, I'll filter that set and none of the gradients will appear. It works fine if I replace the gradients with solid fill colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the Safari developers marked the [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41952) as *works for me*, based on it working in xhtml. For Safari it seems you'd have to serve your webpages with a mime type of application/xhtml+xml or petition the Safari developers to reopen the bug. FWIW it seems like a bug to me.

Comment: the page is not served by any server, as it is a demo at the moment, but i'm using the html5 doctype, which effectively enforces xhtml definition. doesn't that count for something?

Comment: by the way, both testcases in the reported bug *works for me* on Chrome. I'm starting to believe the bug lies in the d3 layer.

Comment: No, the html doctype counts for nothing. The testcases were changed by the webkit developers to have a working mime type, that's why they marked the bug WFM.

Comment: i see. i will try serving the page with a simple server and see what happens.