# Unable to select <linearGradient> with D3.js in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, d3.js, linear-gradients

Chrome doesn't select `<linearGradient>` with D3.js. In the following code all selections are empty.

```js
var defs = d3.select("body").append("svg").append("defs");
defs.append("linearGradient");
defs.append("linearGradient");
console.log(defs.selectAll("linearGradient")); // empty
console.log(defs.selectAll("lineargradient")); // empty
console.log(d3.selectAll("linearGradient")); // empty
```

If you replace `<linearGradient>` with say `<mask>` it's all right.

```js
var defs = d3.select("body").append("svg").append("defs");
defs.append("mask");
defs.append("mask");
console.log(defs.selectAll("mask")); // 2 elements selected
```

Firefox works fine for both. I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.95. Please suggest a way to select the gradients.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linear gradient not applying in Webkit with d3 generated SVG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059394/linear-gradient-not-applying-in-webkit-with-d3-generated-svg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in webkit -- see [the bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83438). The short answer is that for it's just broken. You may be able to work around this by keeping explicit references to the gradients you need to modify, e.g.

```
var grad1 = defs.append("linearGradient");
```

Comment: AHH!! *headdesk* *headdesk*