# rename label in edge in svg canvas using d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am creating a simple graphic environment where users can create node and edge to connect label:

```
function restart() {
        force = d3.layout.force()
                    .nodes(graph.nodes.values())
                    .links(graph.edges.values())
                    .size([width, height])
                    .linkDistance(distance)
                    .linkStrength(strength)
                    .charge(charge)
                    .on('tick', tick);

        //--- paths -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        path = path.data(graph.edges.values());
        // add new links
        var pathCanvas = path.enter().append('svg:g');
        pathCanvas
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
            .attr('class', 'link')
            .style('marker-start', function(d) { return d.left ? 'url(#start-arrow)' : ''; })
            .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
            .style("cursor", "pointer") // change cursor shape
            .style("stroke-width", "3")
            .on('mousedown', function(d) {
                if(d3.event.ctrlKey) {
                    //TODO: use the ctrl key to allow the selection of multiple nodes
                }
                else {
                    showInformationInTextArea(d);
                    pvsWriter.focusOnFun(d, true);
                    clear_selection();
                    selected_edges.set(d.id, d);
                }
            });
        pathCanvas
            .append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return "text:" + d.id; })
            .text(function(d) {
                if(d.target.id == d.source.id) {
                    // text for self edges is rendered as standard text field
                    return d.name;
                }
                // text for other edges is rendered as textpath
                return "";
            })
            .style("cursor", "pointer") // change cursor shape
            .on('mousedown', function(d) { // FIXME: THIS HANDLER IS NEVER TRIGGERED
                if(d3.event.ctrlKey) {
                    //TODO: use the ctrl key to allow the selection of multiple nodes
                }
                else {
                    showInformationInTextArea(d);
                    pvsWriter.focusOnFun(d);
                    clear_selection();
                    selected_edges.set(d.id, d);
                }
            });
        pathCanvas
            .append("svg:text")
            .append("textPath")
            .classed("selected", true)
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return "textPath:" + d.id; })
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#" + d.id; })
            .attr("startOffset", "50%")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) { 
                if(d.target.id == d.source.id) {
                    // text for self edges is rendered as standard text field
                    return "";
                }
                // text for other edges is rendered here
                return d.name;
            })
            .style("cursor", "pointer") // change cursor shape
            // FIXME: THIS HANDLER IS NEVER TRIGGERED -- cant understand why!
            .on('mousedown', function(d) { 
                if(d3.event.ctrlKey) {
                    //TODO: use the ctrl key to allow the selection of multiple nodes
                }
                else {
                    showInformationInTextArea(d);
                    pvsWriter.focusOnFun(d);
                    clear_selection();
                    selected_edges.set(d.id, d);
                }
            });

        // remove old links
        path.exit().remove();

        //--- nodes -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        node = node.data(graph.nodes.values());
        // add new nodes; the svg:g element creates a canvas that allows us to group three shapes together: box, label, resize tool
        var nodeCanvas = node.enter().append('svg:g');
        nodeCanvas
            .append('svg:rect')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr("x", function(d) { return -boxWidth/2; }) // translate x,y so they correspond to the center of the box (rather than the top-left corner)
            .attr("y", function(d) { return -boxHeight/2; })
            .attr("rx", boxWidth/10).attr("ry", boxHeight/10) // rouded edges
            .attr("width", boxWidth).attr("height", boxHeight)
            .attr("id", function(d) {return d.id; })
            .style("cursor", "pointer") // change cursor shape
            .attr("opacity", "0.9")
            .style('fill', function(d) { return (d === selected_node) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id); })
            .style('stroke', function(d) { return d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).darker().toString(); })
            .classed('reflexive', true)
            .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
                if(!mousedown_node || d === mousedown_node) return;
                // enlarge target node
                d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1)');
                if(!mousedown_node || d === mousedown_node) return;
            })
            .on('mousedown', function(d) {
                // update mousedown_node
                mousedown_node = d;
                // create an arrow when the editor is in mode add_transition
                if(editor_mode == MODE.ADD_TRANSITION) {
                    svg.classed('ctrl', true);        
                    // select node
                    if(mousedown_node === selected_node) { selected_node = null; }
                    else { selected_node = mousedown_node; }
                    selected_link = null;
                    // reposition drag line
                    drag_line
                        .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
                        .classed('hidden', false)
                        .attr('d', 'M' + mousedown_node.x + ',' + mousedown_node.y + 'L' + mousedown_node.x + ',' + mousedown_node.y);
                }
                else if(editor_mode == MODE.ADD_SELF_TRANSITION) {
                    // select node
                    selected_node = mousedown_node;
                    selected_link = null;
                    // reposition drag line
                    drag_line
                        .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
                        .classed('hidden', false)
                        .attr('d', function(d) {
                            var ans = 'M' + (mousedown_node.x + 16) + ',' + (mousedown_node.y - 32) + "q 64 -16 16 16";
                            return ans;
                        });
                }
                else {
                    if(d3.event.ctrlKey) {
                        //TODO: use the ctrl key to allow the selection of multiple nodes
                    }
                    else {
                        // if the ctrl key is not pressed, reset selection first, and then select the node
                        clear_node_selection();
                        selected_nodes.set(d.id, d);

                        //START WriterModification: I need to select the node to be able to delete it when user types 'canc'
                        //selected_node = d;
                        //END 

                        // highlight only selected nodes
                        node.selectAll("rect")
                            .style("stroke", function(d) {
                                if(selected_nodes.has(d.id)) { return "black"; }
                                return "";  })
                            .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
                                if(selected_nodes.has(d.id)) { return 2; }
                                return 0;});
                        // showing toolbar node and hidding toolbar edge
                        // update information in the text area
                        showInformationInTextArea(d);
                        // highlight code in the pvs theory
                        pvsWriter.focusOn(d);
                        // and drag nodes if needed
                        node.call(node_drag);
                    }
                    // do not propagate event to parents, otherwhise the selection will be cleared
//                  event.stopPropagation();
                }
                // finally, highlight selected node
                d3.select(this).style("stroke", "black").style("stroke-width", "2");
            })
            .on('mouseup', function(d) {
                // update mouseup_node
                mouseup_node = d;
                if(editor_mode == MODE.ADD_TRANSITION) {
                    if(mousedown_node) {
                        if(mouseup_node != mousedown_node) {
                            // add link to graph (update if exists)
                            var source = mousedown_node;
                            var target = mouseup_node;
                            var direction = 'right';
                            if(graph && graph.edges) {
                                var link = graph.edges.values().filter(function(l) { return (l.source === source && l.target === target); })[0];
                                if(link) { link[direction] = true; } 
                                else { 
                                    add_edge(source, target);
                                    link = graph.edges.values().filter(function(l) { return (l.source === source && l.target === target); })[0];
                                }

                                // automatically select created link, if any has been created
                                if(link) {
                                    clear_selection();
                                    selected_edges.set(link.id, link);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // redraw svg
                        restart();
                    }
                }
                else if(editor_mode == MODE.ADD_SELF_TRANSITION) {
                    // create the self-loops only if the mouse is still on the same source node
                    if(mouseup_node == mousedown_node) { 
                        resetMouseVars();
                        // add self-edge
                        add_edge(d,d);
                        // redraw svg
                        restart();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    showInformationInTextArea(d);
                    pvsWriter.focusOn(d);
                }
            });
        // update existing nodes (reflexive & selected visual states)
        node.selectAll('node')
        .style('fill', function(d) { return (d === selected_node) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.id)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.id); });
        // render resize tool for nodes
        nodeCanvas.append("rect").classed("resizeTool", true)
            .attr("width", 20).attr("height", 20)
            .attr("x", function(d) { return boxWidth/2 - 18; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return boxHeight/2 - 18; }) // place the resize box at the lower right corner of the node
            .attr("rx", 2).attr("ry", 2) // rouded edges
            .attr("stroke", "gray").attr("stroke-width", "2").style("fill", "white") // set colours
            .style("cursor", "se-resize") // change cursor shape
            .attr("opacity", "0.4")
            .on("mousedown", function(d) { 
                node.call(resize);
                });
        // show node IDs
        nodeCanvas.append('svg:text')
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('y', 4)
            .attr('class', 'id')
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
        // remove old nodes
        node.exit().remove();
        // set the graph in motion
        force.start();
    }
```

I also need to edit the label and this is the function I've been using :

```
d3.select("#changeNameEdge")
      .on("click", function () {
            if(selected_edges.keys().length == 1) {
                var object = selected_edges.get(selected_edges.keys());
                var newName = prompt("Please enter new edge label", object.name);
                if( newName && newName.length > 0 ) {
                    var sourceName = object.source.name;
                    var targetName = object.target.name;
                    var id = object.id;
                    var originalName = object.name;
                    var counter = 0;

                    // FIXME: this is not working!
                    path.selectAll("text").text( function(d) {
                        // FIXME: it's not safe to count the occurrences here! Please use the graph structure.
                        if(d.name == originalName ) { counter++; }
                        // self edges store the label in field text; other edges use textPath
                        if(object.source.id == object.target.id){
                            if(d.id == id) { return newName; }
                            return d.name;
                        }
                    });

                    path.selectAll("textPath").text( function(d) {
                        if(d.name == originalName ) { counter++; }
                        if(d.id == id) { return newName; }
                        return d.name;
                    });

                    var newNode = graph.edges.get(id);

                    newNode.name = newName;
                    graph.edges.set(id, newNode);

                    /// Change name in the PVS specification
                    pvsWriter.changeFunName(originalName, newName, sourceName, targetName, counter);             
                    restart();
                }
            }
```

It doesn't work, after calling 'changeNameEdge' the label disappears.

Do you have any suggestion to fix the problem?
If you need I can add some other details of other parts of code.

EDIT:

Briefly:

I am using d3, in particular I have:

```
var graph = { nodes: d3.map(), edges: d3.map() };
```

I create an edge this way:

```
var add_edge = function (source, target, label, notWriter) {
    var _id = "T" + newEdgeID();
    var edge = {
        id: _id, // edge id must be unique
        source: source,
        target: target,
        name : (label === undefined)? "tick" : label,
    };
    // add edge
    graph.edges.set(edge.id, edge);
```

I add text this way:

```
        path = path.data(graph.edges.values());
        // add new links
        var pathCanvas = path.enter().append('svg:g');

pathCanvas
            .append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return "text:" + d.id; })
            .text(function(d) {
                if(d.target.id == d.source.id) {
                    // text for self edges is rendered as standard text field
                    return d.name;
                }
                // text for other edges is rendered as textpath
                return "";
            })
            .style("cursor", "pointer") // change cursor shape
            .on('mousedown', function(d) { // FIXME: THIS HANDLER IS NEVER TRIGGERED
                if(d3.event.ctrlKey) {
                    //TODO: use the ctrl key to allow the selection of multiple nodes
                }
                else {
                    showInformationInTextArea(d);
                    pvsWriter.focusOnFun(d);
                    clear_selection();
                    selected_edges.set(d.id, d);
                }
            });
        pathCanvas
            .append("svg:text")
            .append("textPath")
            .classed("selected", true)
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return "textPath:" + d.id; })
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#" + d.id; })
            .attr("startOffset", "50%")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) { 
                if(d.target.id == d.source.id) {
                    // text for self edges is rendered as standard text field
                    return "";
                }
                // text for other edges is rendered here
                return d.name;
            })
```

And I modify text this way:

```
// FIXME: this is not working!
                    path.selectAll("text").text( function(d) {
                        // FIXME: it's not safe to count the occurrences here! Please use the graph structure.
                        console.log("Entro text"); 
                        if(d.name == originalName ) { counter++; }
                        // self edges store the label in field text; other edges use textPath
                        if(object.source.id == object.target.id){
                            if(d.id == id) { return newName; }
                            return d.name;
                        }
                    });

                    path.selectAll("textPath").text( function(d) {
                        console.log("Entro Path");
                        if(d.name == originalName ) { counter++; }
                        if(d.id == id) { return newName; }
                        return d.name;
                    });

                    var newNode = graph.edges.get(id);

                    newNode.name = newName;
                    graph.edges.set(id, newNode);
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code. Could you post a minimal example that shows the problem please?

Comment: Yes I can, I am going to update my question.

Comment: It seems that when updating the text, you're not returning values in all cases. Even if you're not changing it, you have to return the value, otherwise the text will be empty (i.e. it will seem that it disappeared).

Comment: Oh yeah, I know. But My problem is in changing label 'textPath'

Comment: Ah yes, you have two -- try changing the first to `path.selectAll("text.label")` to only get the first kind of label. I think this may be where things are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks man, things are getting better.
Just a question: Do you know If chrome has bugs in function selectAll("textPath") ?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, why?

Comment: Because in Chromium path.selectAll("textPath") seems to be always empty

Comment: Right, yes -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298318/unable-to-select-lineargradient-with-d3-js-in-chrome

Comment: Ok, so you are suggesting me to keep track of what variable?

Comment: In your case it might be more practical to give those elements a special CSS class that you can select them by.