# D3: selecting `foreignObject` in with tag is not working but with class

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've a `<g>`tag and a with a `<foreignObject>` child tag.
I use D3 to build them and also update them.

I can easily get update the attributes on the `<g>` tag, but Ive problems to reach the `<foreignObject>` tag. I can not get with with `.select('foreignObject')` or `.select('foreignobject')`!

Not working example with.select('foreignObject') : http://jsbin.com/efiDiCAB/4/edit
When I use a class to get the `foreignObject` it is working : http://jsbin.com/efiDiCAB/5/edit

Is there a way to get the `foreignObject` without setting a class on it?
If not, what is the reason for this behavor?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Chrome by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298318/unable-to-select-lineargradient-with-d3-js-in-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not working because a bug in Bug in Webkit: [Unable to select <linearGradient> with D3.js in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298318/unable-to-select-lineargradient-with-d3-js-in-chrome)

Thanks @lars-kotthoff